# Atom 'script' package gives me ModuleNotFoundError with Python

Tags: python, module, atom-editor, importerror

My folder layout is the following:

> folder

> > config.py

> > mainScript.py

Inside the mainScript.py file i run the following line:

```
from config import a, b, c
```

When I run mainScript.py with the Atom package script Then I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/folders/3q/ytqgpk6d7bl69td5z2jxqpfm0000gn/T/atom_script_tempfiles/beda7210-249b-11eb-97fc-47e8e768ffb0", line 12, in 
from config import a, b, c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

However, when I run it in my regular macOS terminal it runs properly. Both the terminal and Atom Script are running python3.

Why is it not properly identifying the location of the config.py file? How do I get it to import it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Always use it like this:

```
from .config import a, b, c
```

Comment: Oh I will keep that in mind. It points it to __main__. But i now receive the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package". It seems like the atom script is not looking in the right place. I do not know how to resolve this.